# Difference between torchmode and flashmode?

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

There seems to be no difference in the two blocks of code below:

```
[self.myDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
[self.myDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
[self.myDevice setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
[self.myDevice unlockForConfiguration];
```

and:

```
[self.myDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
[self.myDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
[self.myDevice unlockForConfiguration];
```

My question is, why is setFlashMode there in the first place, as it seems to have no effect whatsoever. I ask this because I'm trying to get the light to be as bright as it is when you take a picture with the default camera app. Using the light in your own app isn't ever as bright as theirs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code **turn flash light on permanently**

```
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];  // use AVCaptureTorchModeOff to turn on
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
```

until you **set it to off**

```
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];  // use AVCaptureTorchModeOff to turn off
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
```

And below line of is for **Flash light setting** you are making in **camera** - while clicking a pic from iphone

```
[self.myDevice setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
```